# Xamarin Forms Android Error Message Regarding Support Package and other packages

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a complete newbie who has just about started android app. development using Xamarin Forms and VS2012. Only about 20-21 days of exposure I have got. I am trying to learn along the way through writing an imaginary practice app. But there are some errors I am getting. You can see them in the picture.

http://imagebin.ca/v/29PeHoLhwW1i

Can someone direct me what exactly it is saying and what I need to do in order to rectify them?Is there something wrong with the installation/environment or like some update? Or is it something else? What's with the "unzipping failed" message?

Some one kindly help me out here please. Facing great deal of difficulty in tackling this.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what to do to resolve it.  And please do not post links to offsite content, take the time to copy and paste the specific error message into your question.

Comment: @Jason, 

I tried to embed the pic. itself into my post; there's some issue with "minimum reputation".

Anyway, if you could elaborate a bit more on the error scenario, because as per Tanis.7x 's direction, I installed the Support Repository but error condition still remains the same.

Comment: Copy the **text** of the error message(s), not a screenshot.  Posting a screenshot will not help anyone else who has the same problem, because they will never be able find this post by searching on the error message.  That said, try downloading the zip manually and extracting it exactly like the message tells you to.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says (see the third error message ), you need to install the "Android Support Repository" from the Android SDK manager.

The errors are telling you that Xamarin is looking for the support library, but that it cannot find the support library and thus the build failed.

Comment: Hello, @Tanis.7x, I just did the update; actually 2 updates were showing through SDK manager: Android Support Repository and Android M Preview. Installed them both, but the exact same error exists still,

Comment: If you navigate to <android-sdk-`root>\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4`, do you see a folder for 21.0.3?

Comment: Hi.

@Tanis.7x; it's funny, the SDK path the android SDK manager shows through gui, physically if I follow the path, I'm not getting it. Inside Local I have only Temp.

Comment: If that path doesn't exist, that's your problem. You will want to track down the source of that issue, perhaps by deleting your SDK and trying again.

Comment: ok. yes, it well could be.

@Tanis.7x let me check on this one. Most likely this is the problematic part here, causing the errors to show up.

Answer (score 0):

@Tanis.7x and @Jason.

Just an update I want to post:

I went about reproducing this scenario: creating a new project, do some primary simple code, add 1,2 layouts et all. When I build the new project, these 9 errors don't appear. This is strange to me. Because: this is exactly what had happened to my main work also. These errors were not there. Something, somewhere happened along the line, due to which they started appearing suddenly; out of the blue. I remember, I had updated Xamarin version, also just added some packages like JSON.Net and it is only after that this error list appeared. Not before that, if I remember correctly. Which is weird to me. If you try to recreate by creating a brand new project these 9 errors won't appear. I tried recreating this twice; no errors.

Yes, I'm manually downloading the zip file. Hopefully this makes the compiler happy. I'll keep posted about the updates.

Thanks All!